# REST JSON request with Python

Tags: python, json, rest

I am encountering the following error when making a REST request with Python.

Note: This API can help determine whether an individual address is up to date by typing individual address, first name, last name, etc.

Below is my code.

```
import requests
import json

req = requests.get('https://smartmover.melissadata.net/v3/WEB/SmartMover/doSmartMover
?t=1353
&id=428h8f8ghd8u
&jobid=1
&act=NCOA, CCOA
&cols=TransmissionResults,TransmissionReference, Version, TotalRecords,CASSReportLink,NCOAReportLink,Records,AddressExtras,AddressKey,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,AddressTypeCode,BaseMelissaAddressKey,CarrierRoute,City,CityAbbreviation,CompanyName,CountryCode,CountryName,DeliveryIndicator,DeliveryPointCheckDigit,DeliveryPointCode,MelissaAddressKey,MoveEffectiveDate,MoveTypeCode,PostalCode,RecordID,Results,State,StateName,Urbanization
&opt=ProcessingType: Standard
&List=test
&full=PATEL MANISH
&first=MANISH
&last=PATEL
&a1=1600 S 5TH ST                                               
&a2=1600 S 5TH ST                                               
&city=Austin
&state=TX
&postal=78704
&ctry=USA
```

Below is my error.

```
  File "C:\Users\testu\Documents\api.py", line 4
    req = requests.get('https://smartmover.melissadata.net/v3/WEB/SmartMover/doSmartMover
                                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Below is an excerpt from the documentation for REST JSON. (Link: http://wiki.melissadata.com/index.php?title=SmartMover_V3%3AREST_JSON)

**REST Request**

```
https://smartmover.melissadata.net/v3/WEB/SmartMover/doSmartMover
?t={Transmission Reference}
&id={License Key}
&jobid={Job ID}
&pafid={PAF ID}
&act={Actions}
&cols={Columns}
&opt={Options}
&List={List Name}
&comp={Company}
&full={Name Full}
&first={Name First}
&Middle={Name Middle}
&Namepre={Name Prefix}
&Namesfx={Name Suffix}
&last={Name Last}
&u={Urbanization}
&a1={Address Line 1}
&a2={Address Line 2}
&ste={Suite}
&pmb={Private Mailbox}
&city={City}
&state={State}
&postal={Postal Code}
&plus4={Plus4}
&ctry={Country}
&format={Format}
```

Below is an excerpt from the documentation for the request field. (Link: http://wiki.melissadata.com/index.php?title=SmartMover_V3%3ARequest)

> #### Transmission Reference
>
> - Optional. This is a string value that serves as a unique identifier for this set of records. It is returned as sent.
>
>   - REST:    ?t = string
>   - JSON:    "TransmissionReference":"string"

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your string to `requests.get()` is invalid Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a dict to pass the query arguments:

```
url = 'https://smartmover.melissadata.net/v3/WEB/SmartMover/doSmartMover'
qargs = {'t': '...', 'id': '...', ..., 'format': '...'}
response = requests.get(url, params=qargs)
```

Se the documentation: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

The exception you get in your code is a python syntax error, BTW. A python string literal using `'` or `"` is single-line. Python has support for multi-line string literals using `"""` / `'''`.